# Mounting an JSON answer in WebAPI project

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

In my project I'm developing a WebService (using WebAPI 2 with EF6). This service should return a JSON message and it is. But the message is an inconvenient format.

The controller is:

```
public class Arguments
{
    public int arg1{ get; set; }
    public int arg2{ get; set; }
}

[Route("webroute")]
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public IHttpActionResult FindTodos(Arguments args)
{
    return Ok(_repo.BuscaOrdens(args.arg1, args.arg2));
}
```

The repo method is as:

```
public object FindTodos(int arg1, int arg2)
    {
        dynamic nextDeadlines = _ctx.Todos
            .Where(o => o.field1 == arg1 && o.field2 == arg2)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.field3)
            .ThenBy(o => o.ts)
            .Take(10)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Field4,
                x.Field5
            }).ToList();

        dynamic delayed = _ctx.Todos
            .Where(o => o.field1 == arg1 && o.field2 == arg2)
            .OrderBy(o => o.field3)
            .ThenByDescending(o => o.ts)
            .Take(10)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Field4,
                x.Field5
            }).ToList();

        return new List<object> { new List<object> {"NextDeadlines", nextDeadlines}, new List<object> { "Delayed", delayed} };
    }
```

The JSON return it is giving me is:

```
[
    [
        "NextDeadlines",
        [
            {
                "Field4": 2000,
                "Field5": 1.05
            },
            {
                "Field4": 1000,
                "Field5": 1
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        "Delayed",
        [
            {
                "Field4": 500,
                "Field5": 1.1111111111111112
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

And finally what I was expecting to get is something like this:

```
[
    "NextDeadlines":
    [
        {
            "Field4": 2000,
            "Field5": 1.05
        },
        {
            "Field4": 1000,
            "Field5": 1
        }
    ],
    "Delayed":
    [
        {
            "Field4": 500,
            "Field5": 1.1111111111111112
        }
    ]
]
```

Any ideas on what to correct??

Thanks in advance!
Erich

Comment: Maybe returning something like `return new List<object> { "NextDeadlines", nextDeadlines,  "Delayed", delayed };`

Comment: Is it a guess??It didn't associate the objects in the inner Lists as I intended ("NextDeadlines": [ etc... ]). So how will it understand in this form you proposed?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Look at your json and that last line.  You are create a list of  anonymous objects that are lists.  I actually +1 @Hackerman, but the line should be return new List<object> {  new {NextDeadlines = nextDeadlines}, new { Delayed = delayed} };

Comment: @ErichMönch your final json isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

To begin, the json you are expecting is not valid.  I suspect you meant something like

```
[
  {
    "NextDeadlines":
    [
        {
            "Field4": 2000,
            "Field5": 1.05
        },
        {
            "Field4": 1000,
            "Field5": 1
        }
    ],
    "Delayed":
    [
        {
            "Field4": 500,
            "Field5": 1.1111111111111112
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

If that's the case then you need to modify the final line to

```
    return new List<object> { new List<object> {"NextDeadlines", nextDeadlines}, new List<object> { "Delayed", delayed} };
```

to

```
    return new List<object> { new {NextDeadlines = nextDeadlines}, new { Delayed = delayed} };
```

Comment: @Fran, It worked as you said. Now I have the NextDeadlines : [ ...]. Thanks. Now I'd like to know why isn't it correct to have an JSON answer without the outer [ and ]. My ws will always answer just one NextDeadlines and one Delayed. I thought the correct JSON answer would be `{ NextDeadlines: [ ... ], Delayed: [ ... ] }` What am I missing?

Comment: Your web service will return a list of anonymous objects with properties NextDeadlines and Delayed and those properties are both properties are lists. What are you trying to return?

Comment: My web service will always return 2 objects, NextDeadlines and Delayed. And both refer to lists. I thought the entire JSON wouldn't be a list..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "My web service will always return 2 objects." your return line declares a list of objects.  I think you want to return an object that has NextDeadlines and Delayed.  Declare an object with those list properties and return that object.